# Two positive series are equal after some positive integer N implies if one is convergent, then so is the other?

Tags: real-analysis

In my real analysis class we just started our section on series. We've yet to have a class on it, so everything I know is from the textbook, google, and what little I remember from high school calculus. One of the problems from the first section of the book reads:

"Let {an} and {bn} be sequences such that for some positive integer N, an = bn, if n≥N. Prove that if the sum of the sequence an is convergent, then the sum of the sequence bn is convergent." Then it asks how the sum of an compares to that of bn.

I have no idea how to tackle this problem. I've read the same section on series a few times now and I feel like something is missing. I've been thinking something along the lines of how the two sequences themselves are convergent because they are Cauchy, but the chapter had very little about how to show a series is convergent, so I don't think I'm even in the right direction with that at all. Any hints to put me closer to the track I need to be on for this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n = \sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n + \lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=N+1}^{N+M}a_n  = \sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n + \lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=N+1}^{N+M}b_n  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n + \sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n-b_n
$$

Comment: Oh shoot, that actually helps a whole lot. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

There are only finitely many terms in $a_n$ up to index $N$, the same holds for $b_n$, so we can calculate the sum of those terms, let's call these sums $a$ and $b$. We know that $\sum a_n$ converges to some value, say $x$. If we substratc $a$, we are left with the sum of the terms after $N$, which are the same in $b_n$. Now $\sum b_n$ only differs from that with a finite amount $b$.

To be precise:
It's clear that
$$\sum a_n = a + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_n$$
Which is the same as
$$\left(\sum a_n \right) -a= \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_n$$
and for $b_n$ we have the same thing:
$$\left(\sum b_n \right) -b= \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty b_n$$
Clearly the right hand sides are equal because of whats given, so the left hands sides are equal. This rewrites as:
$$\sum b_n = b+\left(\sum a_n\right) -a$$

Comment: To clarify, why is it we know there are only finitely many terms in an? If an and bn are equal when n≥N, wouldn't it only be bounded below by N?

Comment: @karleenamarx Thats exactly what I say..."Up to index N"

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding something

Comment: Ok, I see. I was ignoring the terms for n<N entirely so I assumed you were talking about the terms above N (ie, those which are still infinite because they are only bounded below by N, and not bounded above by anything)

Comment: @karleenamarx I edited to make it more clear

Comment: Ah, that's very clear. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems the question has been answered by now, but since you mentioned Cauchy, I thought I would add a reference to the Cauchy criterion for convergent series.

Remember that a seris is convergent (by definition) if the sequence of partial sums $ S_{an} = \sum_{i=0}^n {a_i} $ converges.

The sequence of partial sums for $a_n$ is convergent iff it satisfies the Cauchy convergence criterion:

$$ |S_{an} - S_{am}| < \epsilon, \qquad m, n > N^*$$

Now if you pick $N^* = N$ you have $S_{an} = b +  S_{bn}  \quad \forall n > N$ where  $b = \sum_0^N a_n -b_n$ is a constant.
Convergence of {$b_n$} follows in the same way since:

$$ |S_{an} - S_{am}| < \epsilon \quad \leftrightarrow \quad |(S_{bn}+b) - S_{bm} + b)| < \epsilon \quad \leftrightarrow \quad |S_{bn} - S_{bm}| < \epsilon \qquad m, n > N^* $$